How to do k-point convergence test?
I'm looking to do a k-point convergence test but I am unsure how to proceed. My current KPOINTS file is:
KPOINTS
0
Gamma
4 1 2
0 0 0

I am aware that it is supposed to converge at 4 1 2 with 160 atoms, but unsure on the process to get there.
Once you do get the results from the convergence test, what would the y-axis values be represented by?

You should not be trying to learn about stuff with 160 atoms. You should be learning about it with a simple system that can complete the calculations quickly.

@naturallyInconsistent's point (that the basics are best learnt on a simple system) are true. Generally, we use the primitive cell of Si (commonly called Si2), as that is just nice, and works very reliably.
The important concepts here is that the concept you are converging is the density of the k-point mesh in reciprocal space. This means that longer reciprocal lattice vectors require more points to achieve the same density. It is worth recalling that the ratios of reciprocal lattice vectors are the inverse of the ratio of the real space lattice vectors, so the smaller the real space lattice, the more points that you will need in that direction. So, generally it is common practice to keep the k-points in the same ratio as the reciprocal lattice vectors, and then scale from there.
The next point is to know what you are converging. The most common quantity you will see being converged is the total energy (however this is not always the most appropriate quantity: for example, when converging to prepare for a phonon calculation you will find that stress is a better proxy for your phonon mode convergence than the total energy of your system).
Accordingly, the first step of converging your k-points is to run your code to extract your chosen convergence parameter for that system. Then note what this was, and run again with a denser k-point mesh. You should find that your answer will not be the same (at least, not the same to N decimal places). Now run it again with an even denser grid. You should find that the answers are not the same, but will be identical to a higher number of decimal places.
The aim of convergence testing is to determine when you can stop increasing your number (in this case, your k-points). This is the point where there is no universal answer. If you are investigating properties on the 10 eV energy scale (for the sake of argument) converging to 10 meV would be sufficient to claim accuracy, whereas for properties on the meV scale, that same threshold would be woeful: it is all about the signal (the property you care about) to noise (uncertainty due to incomplete convergence) ratio. Ultimately, deciding what threshold is "converged" is up to you as a scientist to decide.
Hope that helps,
Rob

Following the recommendations above given by @robert-lawrence, the fast way to implement his advice is to use a script that creates the input files, one at a time, for a given set of k-points. Then optimize the system (or calculate the property you want to converge. From the output files, get the property value and the k-point used and add to a table. Then plot the data.
Below is an old script used to study the convergence of the total energy as a function of the mess cut-off parameter using the SIESTA software.
#!/bin/bash
#rm E_vs_h.dat
tmp=0
# Numero de pontos para fazer a curva Energia vs h
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
do
tmp=`echo "$i" | bc`
mesh=`echo "150+$i*25" | bc` 
cat > BN_SWNT_MeshCutoff-$i.fdf <<!

SystemName          BN_SWNT_MeshCutoff-$i
SystemLabel         BN_SWNT_MeshCutoff-$i

NumberOfAtoms    120
NumberOfSpecies  2

%block ChemicalSpeciesLabel
    1    7  N
    2    5  B
%endblock ChemicalSpeciesLabel

LatticeConstant 1.0 Ang
%block LatticeParameters
  19.732500  19.732500  12.780000  90.000000  90.000000  90.000000
%endblock LatticeParameters

AtomicCoordinatesFormat NotScaledCartesianAng
%block AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
   13.83449859    9.97218526    0.70792856   2       1  B
   13.88703720    9.97257250    2.13204539   1       2  N
   13.61137793   11.19419824    2.83801327   2       3  B
   13.65851851   11.21138862    0.00237940   1       4  N
   13.01712386   12.28595915    0.70829688   2       5  B
   13.05936802   12.31769682    2.13195531   1       6  N
   12.11345363   13.13753520    2.83848680   2       7  B
   12.14392778   13.18244285    0.00236737   1       8  N
   10.99327298   13.67347975    0.70812820   2       9  B
   11.00710824   13.72275322    2.13209069   1      10  N
    9.76028617   13.83450331    2.83806217   2      11  B
    9.75995195   13.88703014    0.00214602   1      12  N
    8.53829948   13.61137958    0.70789208   2      13  B
    8.52112956   13.65852150    2.13227472   1      14  N
    7.44655823   13.01713343    2.83841005   2      15  B
    7.41480598   13.05935655    0.00210116   1      16  N
    6.59497932   12.11345223    0.70832091   2      17  B
    6.55004741   12.14393668    2.13227488   1      18  N
    6.05902086   10.99330487    2.83822450   2      19  B
    6.00975653   11.00706338    0.00225647   1      20  N
    5.89800140    9.76031475    0.70792856   2      21  B
    5.84546280    9.75992751    2.13204539   1      22  N
    6.12112207    8.53830177    2.83801327   2      23  B
    6.07398149    8.52111138    0.00237940   1      24  N
    6.71537614    7.44654085    0.70829688   2      25  B
    6.67313199    7.41480317    2.13195531   1      26  N
    7.61904637    6.59496480    2.83848680   2      27  B
    7.58857221    6.55005716    0.00236737   1      28  N
    8.73922703    6.05902025    0.70812820   2      29  B
    8.72539175    6.00974678    2.13209069   1      30  N
    9.97221383    5.89799668    2.83806217   2      31  B
    9.97254804    5.84546986    0.00214602   1      32  N
   11.19420052    6.12112042    0.70789208   2      33  B
   11.21137044    6.07397850    2.13227472   1      34  N
   12.28594177    6.71536657    2.83841005   2      35  B
   12.31769402    6.67314344    0.00210117   1      36  N
   13.13752068    7.61904777    0.70832092   2      37  B
   13.18245260    7.58856333    2.13227488   1      38  N
   13.67347914    8.73919512    2.83822450   2      39  B
   13.72274347    8.72543662    0.00225647   1      40  N
   13.83449650    9.97219678    4.96797262   2      41  B
   13.88703014    9.97254805    6.39214602   1      42  N
   13.61137958   11.19420051    7.09789207   2      43  B
   13.65849816   11.21137107    4.26236088   1      44  N
   13.01710441   12.28596975    4.96825493   2      45  B
   13.05935655   12.31769402    6.39210117   1      46  N
   12.11345223   13.13752068    7.09832092   2      47  B
   12.14395804   13.18243018    4.26239178   1      48  N
   10.99329770   13.67348599    4.96808178   2      49  B
   11.00706338   13.72274348    6.39225648   1      50  N
    9.76031475   13.83449859    7.09792857   2      51  B
    9.75990202   13.88703070    4.26218971   1      52  N
    8.53830865   13.61138837    4.96787519   2      53  B
    8.52111137   13.65851852    6.39237940   1      54  N
    7.44654085   13.01712387    7.09829689   2      55  B
    7.41478808   13.05934362    4.26211121   1      56  N
    6.59498048   12.11347614    4.96833387   2      57  B
    6.55005715   12.14392778    6.39236737   1      58  N
    6.05902025   10.99327298    7.09812820   2      59  B
    6.00976433   11.00710442    4.26224438   1      60  N
    5.89800350    9.76030323    4.96797262   2      61  B
    5.84546986    9.75995196    6.39214602   1      62  N
    6.12112042    8.53829948    7.09789208   2      63  B
    6.07400184    8.52112893    4.26236089   1      64  N
    6.71539559    7.44653025    4.96825493   2      65  B
    6.67314344    7.41480598    6.39210117   1      66  N
    7.61904776    6.59497932    7.09832092   2      67  B
    7.58854196    6.55006981    4.26239178   1      68  N
    8.73920230    6.05901402    4.96808178   2      69  B
    8.72543663    6.00975653    6.39225648   1      70  N
    9.97218525    5.89800141    7.09792857   2      71  B
    9.97259798    5.84546930    4.26218972   1      72  N
   11.19419134    6.12111163    4.96787519   2      73  B
   11.21138863    6.07398148    6.39237940   1      74  N
   12.28595915    6.71537613    7.09829688   2      75  B
   12.31771192    6.67315638    4.26211121   1      76  N
   13.13751952    7.61902386    4.96833387   2      77  B
   13.18244285    7.58857222    6.39236737   1      78  N
   13.67347975    8.73922702    7.09812820   2      79  B
   13.72273567    8.72539558    4.26224438   1      80  N
   13.83450331    9.97221383    9.22806217   2      81  B
   13.88703070    9.97259798   10.65218971   1      82  N
   13.61138837   11.19419134   11.35787519   2      83  B
   13.65852151   11.21137044    8.52227472   1      84  N
   13.01713343   12.28594177    9.22841005   2      85  B
   13.05934362   12.31771192   10.65211121   1      86  N
   12.11347614   13.13751952   11.35833386   2      87  B
   12.14393668   13.18245259    8.52227488   1      88  N
   10.99330488   13.67347915    9.22822450   2      89  B
   11.00710443   13.72273568   10.65224437   1      90  N
    9.76030322   13.83449650   11.35797262   2      91  B
    9.75992750   13.88703720    8.52204539   1      92  N
    8.53830176   13.61137793    9.22801327   2      93  B
    8.52112893   13.65849816   10.65236089   1      94  N
    7.44653025   13.01710441   11.35825493   2      95  B
    7.41480318   13.05936802    8.52195531   1      96  N
    6.59496480   12.11345363    9.22848679   2      97  B
    6.55006982   12.14395803   10.65239178   1      98  N
    6.05901401   10.99329769   11.35808178   2      99  B
    6.00974677   11.00710825    8.52209068   1     100  N
    5.89799668    9.76028617    9.22806217   2     101  B
    5.84546929    9.75990202   10.65218972   1     102  N
    6.12111163    8.53830866   11.35787519   2     103  B
    6.07397849    8.52112956    8.52227472   1     104  N
    6.71536657    7.44655823    9.22841005   2     105  B
    6.67315638    7.41478808   10.65211121   1     106  N
    7.61902387    6.59498048   11.35833387   2     107  B
    7.58856333    6.55004741    8.52227488   1     108  N
    8.73919512    6.05902085    9.22822450   2     109  B
    8.72539558    6.00976433   10.65224438   1     110  N
    9.97219678    5.89800350   11.35797262   2     111  B
    9.97257250    5.84546280    8.52204539   1     112  N
   11.19419824    6.12112207    9.22801327   2     113  B
   11.21137107    6.07400184   10.65236088   1     114  N
   12.28596975    6.71539559   11.35825493   2     115  B
   12.31769682    6.67313198    8.52195531   1     116  N
   13.13753520    7.61904637    9.22848680   2     117  B
   13.18243019    7.58854196   10.65239179   1     118  N
   13.67348599    8.73920230   11.35808178   2     119  B
   13.72275323    8.72539175    8.52209069   1     120  N
%endblock AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies

PAO.BasisSize     DZP
MD.TypeOfRun      CG
MD.NumCGsteps     100
MaxSCFIterations  500
SpinPolarized     .true.
MeshCutoff        $mesh Ry
DM.MixingWeight   0.01
DM.NumberPulay    3
XC.functional     LDA
XC.authors        CA
SolutionMethod diagon
# Fim do input para o SIESTA
!
mpirun -np 12 siesta < BN_SWNT_MeshCutoff-$i.fdf > BN_SWNT_MeshCutoff-$i.out
E=$(grep "siesta:         Total" BN_SWNT_MeshCutoff-$i.out | grep '='| awk '{printf "%12.6f \n",$4}')
echo $mesh $E $i >> E_vs_mesh.dat
done

In this script:

There is a for loop with 20 points: for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
The value of the mesh is calculated for each value of the loop: mesh=`echo "150+$i*25" | bc
Export the input file using command cat: cat > BN_SWNT_MeshCutoff-$i.fdf <<! (here is input value has the value of the loop variable at the name).
run the SIESTA calculation for each input file: mpirun -np 12 siesta < BN_SWNT_MeshCutoff-$i.fdf > BN_SWNT_MeshCutoff-$i.out
Extract the total energy value from the corresponding output:  E=$(grep "siesta:         Total" BN_SWNT_MeshCutoff-$i.out | grep '='| awk '{printf "%12.6f \n",$4}')
Export the extracted values to a data file: echo $mesh $E $i >> E_vs_mesh.dat
Plot the E_vs_mesh.dat

